# jQuery .ajax: How to handle Custom Validation Error Message, REST API, 400 status code?

Tags: php, jquery, rest

What's the best way handle a 400 error (form validation error) with a Custom Error Message (Simple Text) from a jQuery .ajax call to a REST API. I'm trying to return the validation message with the response data. But, if I return a status code of 400 the .ajax used the error function. Only the success seems to be able to easily pull the 'response' data, which include my 'message'.

Snippet of REST API PHP CodeIgniter:

```
    $id = $this->contact_model->insert($put);

    if (!empty($id))
    {
        $this->response(array('result' => true, 'id' => $id), 200);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('result' => false, 
                   'message' => strip_tags(validation_errors())), 400);
    }
```

jQuery .ajax Snippet of code:

```
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo site_url('rest_api/contacts')."?format=json"; ?>',
type: "put",
data: $('#subpanel-contacts-add-form').serialize(),
success: function(response) {
    if (response.result == true) {
        // Add Relationship collection_contact_put
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('rest_api/collections'); ?>/' + collection_id + '/contacts/' + response.id + '?format=json',
            type: "put",
            data: {},
            success: function(relresponse) {
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#subpanel-contacts-form-result").html('<div class="alert alert-error">Error: The Contact could not be saved! ' + response.message + '</div>');
    }
},
error: function() {
    $("#subpanel-contacts-form-result").html('<div class="alert alert-error">Error: There was an error while submitting!</div>');
}   
});
```

I'm trying to work with the 'response' object; parameters message and result. I'm not sure if there is a better way to handle the response on error code. Should I be using .done .always and/or .fail. Should I base it off of status code returned?

Edit: Noticed I got the PUT/POST mixed.

Comment: 400 is a "Bad Request" error code.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP you can set custom status code/message with :

```
header("HTTP/1.1 $statusCode $message");
```

Where

- $statusCode = the HTTP status code you wish to send (use 521-529 for custom errors)
- $message = A text string describing the error.

Client-side, you can pick up these two pieces of data in your ajax error handler as follows :

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var HTTP_status = jqXHR.status;
    var message = errorThrown;
    ...
}
```

`jqXHR.responseText` may also contain a meaningful string (or json-encoded data) depending on what occurred server-side.

Comment: Yea, I later discovered the data I needed was in jqXHR.responseText, which when parseJSON() was applied gave me my data object. Then I could use the custom validation message -> response.message.

Answer (score 0):

I hate it when this happens. 30 minutes later, I think I figured out a way to output the response message on failure. I'm still not sure if it's the best approach. I would love to hear from others on this question.

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
    $("#subpanel-contacts-form-result").html('<div class="alert alert-error">Error: There was an error while submitting! ' + response.message + '</div>');
}
```